# Converting a primitive structure to conventional standard with pymatgen?

Tags: python, pymatgen

How do I convert a primitive structure to the conventional standard representation with pymatgen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, use the SpacegroupAnalyzer object.

```
from pymatgen.symmetry.analyzer import SpacegroupAnalyzer
SGA = SpacegroupAnalyzer(primitive_structure)
conventional_structure = SGA.get_conventional_standard_structure()
```